# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data OK

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have problem with my script, there is an error on JSON response.
Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#btndouble').click(function(){
      var address = $('#btcaddress').val();
      var ref_name = $('#ref_name').val();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {address:address,ref:ref_name},
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#btndouble').attr('disabled','disabled');
        },
        complete: function() {
          $('#btndouble').removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        success: function(json) {
          if(json.success){
            $('#response').html(json.response);
          } else {
            $('#error_msg').html(json.response);
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
    })
})
```

Ajax.php code
`

```
require 'model/connect.php';
require 'btcaddress.php';

if(isset($_POST['address'])) {

    $post_addr = trim($_POST['address']);

    // local BTC address validation
    $validator = new Btc_address_validator();
    $check = $validator->validate($post_addr);
    if($check=='1') {


        // Check BTC address is admin wallet address?

        $select_wallet = "SELECT admin_address FROM invetment WHERE admin_address='".$post_addr."'";
        $wallet_res = mysql_query($select_wallet);

        if(mysql_num_rows($wallet_res) == '0') {


            // BTC address already not paid status there?
            // $select_sql = "SELECT * FROM invetment WHERE user_address='".$post_addr."' AND status='0'";
            $select_sql = "SELECT * FROM invetment WHERE user_address='".$post_addr."'";
            $res = mysql_query($select_sql);

            if(mysql_num_rows($res) == '0') {

                $select_sql1 = "SELECT * FROM invetment WHERE user_address='".$post_addr."' AND status='1'";
                $res1 = mysql_query($select_sql1);
                if(mysql_num_rows($res1) == 0 ) {

                    require 'lib/block_io.php';


                    $merchant = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `payment_process` WHERE payment_id='1' AND withdraw_option='1' "));
                    if($merchant) {

                        $apikey = base64_decode(base64_decode(base64_decode($merchant['account_id'])));
                        $pin = base64_decode(base64_decode(base64_decode($merchant['spwd'])));

                        $version = 2;

                        $block_io = new BlockIo($apikey, $pin, $version);

                        $address_array = $block_io->get_new_address();

                        $address_info = $address_array->data;
                        if($address_info->network=='BTC') {
                            $admin_address = $address_info->address;
                        }

                        // $random_address = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wallets` WHERE status='0' ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1"));
                        if($admin_address) {
                            // $admin_address = $random_address['address'];
                            $label_value = '';
                            foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
                                $label_value1 = md5($key.'1d61b689-c8a8-402e-a344-sa7773994356');
                                if($value == $label_value1) {
                                    $label_value = md5($key.'1d61b689-c8a8-402e-a344-sa7773994356');
                                }
                            }

                            if($label_value=='') {

                                // create label
                                $label = rand('00000','11111').time();

                                // convert ms5
                                $label_value = md5($label.'1d61b689-c8a8-402e-a344-sa7773994356');
                                // set cookie
                                $cookie_status = setcookie($label, $label_value, time() * 3600000, "/", NULL);
                                if(!$cookie_status) {
                                    setrawcookie($label, $label_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
                                }
                            }
                            $sponsor = ($_POST['ref']) ? $_POST['ref'] : '';
                            $myref = $post_addr;
                            $invest_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO invetment SET label='".$label_value."', user_address='".$post_addr."', admin_address='".$admin_address."', invest_date='".$invest_date."', status='0', userip='".$ip."', ref_name='".$myref."', sponsor='".$sponsor."'";
                            $qry_status = mysql_query($sql);
                            if($qry_status) {
                                // mysql_query("UPDATE wallets SET status='1' WHERE address='".$admin_address."'");
                                $json['success'] = "1";
                                $json['message1'] = "Send your Bitcoins to";
                                $json['message2'] = $admin_address;
                                $json['message3'] = "(Min - 0.001 BTC, Max - unlimited)";
                            } else {
                                $json['error'] = "1";
                                $json['message'] = "Unable to process your BTC Address. Try again";
                            }
                        } else {
                            $json['error'] = "1";
                            $json['message'] = "The service or data is temporarily not available. Try again";
                        }
                    } 
                    else {
                        $json['error'] = "1";
                        $json['message'] = "The service or data is temporarily not available. Contact support team";
                    }
                } else {
                    $result = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
                    $label = $result['label'];
                    $label_value = md5($label.'1d61b689-c8a8-402e-a344-sa7773994356');
                    $cookie_status = setcookie($label, $label_value, time() * 3600000, "/", NULL);
                    if(!$cookie_status) {
                        setrawcookie($label, $label_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
                    }
                    $json['error'] = "1";
                    $json['message'] = "Invalid BTC Address. Try again";
                }
            } else {

                $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                $label = $result['label'];
                $label_value = md5($label.'1d61b689-c8a8-402e-a344-sa7773994356');
                $cookie_status = setcookie($label, $label_value, time() * 3600000, "/", NULL);
                if(!$cookie_status) {
                    setrawcookie($label, $label_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
                }
                if($result['status']=='0') {
                    $json['success'] = "1";
                    $json['message1'] = "Send your Bitcoins to";
                    $json['message2'] = $result['admin_address'];
                    $json['message3'] = "(Min - 0.001 BTC, Max - unlimited)";   
                } else {
                    $json['error'] = "1";
                    $json['message'] = "Already exists this BTC Address";
                }

            }

        } else {

            $json['error'] = "1";
            $json['message'] = "Invalid BTC Address already used";
        } 


    } else {
        $json['error'] = "1";
        $json['message'] = "Invalid BTC Address";
    }

} else {
    $json['error'] = "1";
    $json['message'] = "pls enter BTC Address";
}

if(isset($json['success'])==1) {
    $json['response'] = "<div class='col-lg-12'><h3>".$json['message1']." <span>".$json['message2']."</span><br/> ".$json['message3']."</h3></div>";
} else {
    $json['response'] = $json['message'];
    // echo $json['message'];
}
echo json_encode($json); ?>`
```

When I click SUBMIT button in my Form, show this error
"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
OK" 
I am new in this code, Please someone help me to fix this problem
Thank you so much

Comment: This error occurred when you try to parse JSON data which are not properly stringified

Comment: What should I do to fix it ?

Comment: Try running the JSON it's trying to parse through https://jsonlint.com/ and see if you can figure out where your JSON is malformed.

Comment: @DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree .. I am really new in this code. Can you help me to check?

I pasted my code there, and show me this error
Error: Parse error on line 1:
  $(document).ready(fu
--^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: You need to show us the PHP code and the payload sent from your server.

Comment: I have posted ajax.php code above , could you tell me which payload do you mean

Comment: `mysql_query`? That was removed from PHP years ago. First thing you should do is upgrade your PHP and find a proper database API, then learn about debugging front-end code using your browser's network inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Json format.try like this

```js
$('#btndouble').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('#btcaddress').val()!="")
    {
      var DateValue = [{ "name": "address", "value": $('#btcaddress').val() }, { "name": "ref_name", "value":$('#ref_name').val()}, ];
      var sdata = JSON.stringify(DateValue);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: sdata,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#btndouble').attr('disabled','disabled');
        },
        complete: function() {
          $('#btndouble').removeAttr('disabled');
        },
        success: function(json) {
          if(json.success){
            $('#response').html(json.response);
          } else {
            $('#error_msg').html(json.response);
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
      }else
      alert("Plese Enter a value");
    })
```

Comment: I try use your code.. Here is my demo http://bitcoin-doubler-2018.spiderscript.net/
When I click The DOUBLE COIN button, its show me other response. like I didn't entered any data in field.

Comment: What is your rewuirement on buttonclick?you need the text field value in json format right? @John

Comment: Yes right.. its should be response from block.io about payment  instruction to btc address.

Comment: inspect and check, this data is passed and you are getting the response back . when i entered hai and pressed the button , request went with data as {"mydata":"[{\"name\":\"address\",\"value\":\"haii\"},{\"name\":\"ref_name\",\"value\":\"\"}]"}:  and getting response as {error: "1", message: "pls enter BTC Address", response: "pls enter BTC Address"}. what else you need?

Comment: but The response "Pls Enter BTC address" should be shown if I don't fill anything in field then click Button.. but even I entered btc address in field.. JSON still give error response.

Comment: that message you are returning from the response right? i dont know what condition you have written in backend. you can handle validation from frontend itself right? @john

Comment: Can  I send you ajax.php source code? so then you can check.. I am new in code, and very thankful for your help

Comment: BTW, this json code I posted above works in other server without SyntaxError.. but in some servers this problem occured..

Comment: I've edited the code. the format we changed now right, so maybe it won't hit the exact condition. please check from your side, please @John

Comment: still same problem :)
Even entered btc address, form always said "pls enter BTC address", 
This code should appear if we fill btc address correctly there.
if($result['status']=='0') {
           $json['success'] = "1";
      $json['message1'] = "Send your Bitcoins to";
      $json['message2'] = $result['admin_address'];
      $json['message3'] = "(Min - 0.001 BTC, Max - unlimited)";

Comment: check what value is coming in $result['status'] and to which block it is going.

Comment: as per your code $result['status'] is not equal to zero. always going to else block. where you are assigning $result['status']?? show me that part

Comment: @John Brother, can you check what value is coming in  $result['status']? put breakpoint or print and check.

Comment: Brother, this site used same script http://cryptothunder.net/ , you can try enter BTC address there and see the result shown :)

Comment: $check = $validator->validate($post_addr); always not equal to 1. so it wont execute your if condition.always it will go to else and returns "pls enter BTC Address". I think what value we are passing from frontend is not fetching in ajax.php

Comment: I am new in code :)
Can you tell me the correct condition for it? what correction I must do there?